# Dynamically created inline editable DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, inline

I'm creating a Dynamic data-table, which pulls data from SQL and generates both the Columns and the Rows with information based on the return Query. I'm doing this dynamically because i have 8 different grids and i don't want to create a page for each one!

I'm adding information via a modal with all the columns (also generated dynamically in the code above but not very UX friendly) and via excel file (with the same structure also).

How can I make this table editable inline? Is this possible, taking in consideration, the way I'm building this table?

Table has some flaws such as it makes two ajax requests... one for the creation of the table and another when it's created (basically the same request because it's the request that refreshes the data when I add more data or search one of the columns for specific information). So if you have tips on how i can do only one ajax request instead of making two on load feel free to share also. :)

Thank you all!

```
//Here is where the table is create by Ajax Request
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Parametrization/Detail")',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: jsonTest,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr)
            {
                if (data.data.length > 0) {
                    //Gets all columns and generates a ColumnSet
                    js = JSON.parse(data.data[0].tableColsName)
                    cols = generateDynamicColumns(js)

                    //Here is where the Header and the Modal are defined dynamically
                    cols.forEach(function (index) {
                        //Header
                        $('#tblSearch_ thead tr:eq(0)').append('<th>' + index.name + '</th>');
                        //Modal
                        $('#modal-bd').append('<div class="form-group"> <label>' + index.name
                            + '</label> <input required class="form-control" id="'
                            + index.data + '" type="' + index.type + '" /> </div>');
                    });


                    //Here is where the search bar is defined dynamically
                    $('#tblSearch_ thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#tblSearch_ thead');
                    $('#tblSearch_ thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (index) {

                        $(this).html('<input class="form-control" id="search" name="title" type="' + cols[index].type + '" placeholder="Procurar ' + cols[index].name + '" />');

                        $(this).find(':input').each(function () {
                            $(this).on('keyup change', function () {
                                if (tempTable.column(index).search() !== this.value) {
                                    tempTable
                                        .column(index)
                                        .search(this.value);
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    });

                    // Here is where the table is created dynamically
                    tempTable = $('#tblSearch_').DataTable({
                        dom: "Brtip",
                        paging: true,
                        pageLength: @Model._configuration.PageSize,
                        orderCellsTop: true,
                        fixedHeader: true,
                        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                            input = (function () {
                                aux = {
                                    "pageNumber": (data.start / data.length) + 1,
                                    "pageSize": data.length,
                                    "OrderFieldBy": data.columns[data.order[0].column].data + '.' + data.order[0].dir
                                }
                                data.columns.forEach(v => {
                                    str = v.search.value
                                    if (str) {
                                        aux[v.data] = str
                                    }
                                    while (str.charAt(0) === ',') {
                                        str = str.substr(1);
                                    }
                                    aux[v.data + 'Search'] = str
                                })
                                return aux
                            }).call()

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Content("~/Parametrization/Detail")',
                                type: 'POST',
                                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                                },
                                data: JSON.stringify(input),
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                                    callback({
                                        data: data.data,
                                        recordsTotal: data.recordsTotal,
                                        recordsFiltered: data.recordsFiltered
                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    fnHasFormError(jqXhr.responseJSON.message, 'errorMessages_modal')
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        columns: cols,
                        serverSide: true,
                        'bRetrieve': true,
                        processing: true,
                        responsive: true,
                        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
                        "info": true,
                        "lengthMenu": [10],
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "pagingType": "full",
                          "buttons": [{ extend: "create", editor: editor },
                                  { extend: "edit", editor: editor },
                                  { extend: "remove", editor: editor } ],
                        language: {
                            "sProcessing": "A processar...",
                            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos",
                            "sZeroRecords": "Não foram encontrados resultados",
                            "sInfo": "Elementos mostrados  _START_ - _END_ em _TOTAL_",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registos no total)",
                            "sInfoPostFix": "",
                            "sSearch": "Procurar:",

                            paginate: {
                                'sFirst': '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                                'sLast': '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                                'sPrevious': '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                                'sNext': '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
                            },
                            aria: {
                                paginate: {
                                    first: 'First',
                                    previous: 'Previous',
                                    next: 'Next',
                                    last: 'Last'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    table = tempTable;
                } else {
                    fnHasFormError("Não existem registos relativos a esta parametrização", 'errorMessages_modal')
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                fnHasFormError(jqXhr.responseJSON.message, 'errorMessages_modal')
            }
        });
```